# Calculate the Hash of the Contents of a File in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to calculate the Hash of the Contents of a File in C#? So, that I can compare two file hashes in my app. I have search but not found.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could use `MD5CryptoServiceProvider`, which will work with text based files as well as binary files.

```
byte[] myFileData = File.ReadAllBytes(myFileName);
byte[] myHash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(myFileData);
```

Or... if you work with large files and do not want to load the whole file into memory:

```
byte[] myHash;
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(myFileName))
    myHash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
```

You can compare to byte arrays from two files with `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`:

```
myHash1.SequenceEqual(myHash2);
```

You could also try to create an CRC-calculator. See: http://damieng.com/blog/2006/08/08/calculating_crc32_in_c_and_net

Comment: Is it really necessary to convert the whole file into a byte array?

Comment: @MartinMulder, can i use Dictionary to store hash and compare it by TryGetValue?)) hash of hash))

Comment: @MartinMulder,Hm...it not works with dictionary....

Comment: @AdmiralLand: I think your question is completely off-topic. Your question is about using a byte-array as a key in a dictionary. Perhaps you can create a new question.

Comment: How do yu get the string value of the byte?

Answer (score 9):

**You should search better ;)**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;


protected string GetMD5HashFromFile(string fileName)
{
  FileStream file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
  MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
  byte[] retVal = md5.ComputeHash(file);
  file.Close();

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < retVal.Length; i++)
  {
    sb.Append(retVal[i].ToString("x2"));
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Pass your file to this function like this.

```
GetMD5HashFromFile("text1.txt");
GetMD5HashFromFile("text2.txt");
```

Comment: Is it really necesery to convert the whole byte array into a string? I seemds like a bit much work for just compare the two hashes.

Comment: You should use `using` on the stream instead of explicitly calling `Close()`.