# Getting Memory Out of Range exception for static method

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am getting `Memory Out of Range` exception for my static method which compares the two jpeg files.

I am able to identify which part of my code is consuming the most memory using the profiler, however, I am not able to free up the memory, even I tried GC.Collect()

```
public static bool IsDuplicate(string newFile, string pathDestination)
{
    string[] destinationFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pathDestination); // 1100 jpeg files.
    foreach (var file in destinationFiles)
    {
        if (CompareImageFiles(newFile, file))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//1100 jpeg files (pathFile2) being compared with one jpeg file (pathFile1)
public static bool CompareImageFiles(string pathFile1, string pathFile2)
{
     // Memory consumption around 1 GB by ms
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
     // Memory consumption around 2.7 GB by img1
    System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(pathFile1);

     // Memory consumption around 3 GB by img2
    System.Drawing.Image img2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(pathFile2);
    if (!(img1.Height == img2.Height && img1.Width == img2.Width))
    {
        return false;   // Dimensions mismatch
    }
    else
    {
        img1.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        string image1 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        img2.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        string image2 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        if (image1.Equals(image2))
        {
             // This didn't work
            //ms = null; img1 = null; img2 = null; image1 = null; image2 = null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
             // This didn't work
            //ms = null; img1 = null; img2 = null; image1 = null; image2 = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**A Little background:** Yes, I do understand that this is not the perfect approach for comparing the image files (*my 1st attempt at dealing with image files*). I had already started the new optimised version of this task (*In progress*).

*However, since this solution was working since the last couple of months and recently started breaking. So, before I would have archived this approach at least I wanted to fix the issue which gave me a good learning.*

Comment: How about first comparing file-sizes to cull down on processing? Then you hash the files and compare the hashes - if they differ they are internally different as well. No need for this image stuff? Should be much faster and much more resource friendly then what you do.

Comment: Your app is leaking.  Anything which implements a `Dispose` method must be disposed when you are done with it.

Comment: Try this:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16318177/7505395

Comment: From what I see, you don't care about the image itself, you only want to know if you are comparing diffent files (I mean, you are not interested whether the images in the files represent the same subject). If so, as already suggested, first check the file lenght. If it's identical, you can by binary-search a partial content of the file in different positions. The chance that two images, that are not a duplicate file, have the same binary content in different sections is almost non-existant. But this depends on how precise you have to be. What to avoid is loading the whole image im memory.

Comment: @PatrickArtner : Yes, Your suggestion (using hashes) is really thoughtful. Thanks.

Comment: @downvoter I believe I have improved the quality of my question please have another look.

Comment: @Jimi : I had thought of using this "binary-search a partial content" approach (in my newer version), however, it fails in case of same images of different resolutions. I understand it is a good fit if there is no chance of same images of different resolutions.

Comment: Well, that's easily overcome, by reading the file header. Jpeg and Png formats specify their "density" in the header. Other do. You could build a struct modelled on the header and binary-read it. It's a bit more "sophisticated" (may require a little more study), but it's really, really fast. And you don't eat up memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should dispose of your `Image` instances and the memory stream, either by placing them in a `using` statement or by manually calling `Dispose()` when you're done with them:

```
public static bool CompareImageFiles(string pathFile1, string pathFile2)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(pathFile1))
    using (var img2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(pathFile2))
    {
        // Rest of your code...
    }
}
```

Comment: To add, in general using “using” is the preferred way as it also handles proper disposal in case exceptions occur. Dispose should only be called directly if one can’t use “using” or in Dispose methods/finalizers.